# Avoid Button Press When Pressing Space

Tags: jquery

I have some keyboard shortcuts with jQuery

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    ..
```

and then I have a button function

```
function lifeChange1($life) {
    ..
```

The problem is when you've pressed the button and then afterwards press space, the site runs the button function where it's ment to run the keypress function instead.

Is it possible to like not select the button when pressed and just run the function?

Comment: what u have tried, post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//To handle space button
$(function() {
 $(document).keyup(function(evt) {
   if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
  return false;
  }
  }).keydown(function(evt) {
if (evt.keyCode == 32) {
  return true;
}
 });
 }
```